# KeyStore not saving to file

Tags: java, security, keystore, private-key

I am trying to store multiple private keys in a JKS file using the Java KeyStore library. I created a method which writes and reads to the JKS file but the private key isn't being saved in the file.

When I store something into the KeyStore I can get all the aliases in the keystore and the new key is there. Once the method is closed and the same key is attempted to be pulled it does not find the key.

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Create keys
    main m = new main();
    m.getOrSetPrivateKey("123", "123", privateKey, false);

    PrivateKey p = m.getOrSetPrivateKey("123", "123", null, true);

    if (p.equals(c.getPriv_key()))
        System.err.println("Equal");
    else
        System.err.println("Not equal !!!!!!!!");

}


private synchronized PrivateKey getOrSetPrivateKey(String alias, String id, PrivateKey c, boolean read ) throws InterruptedException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, InvalidKeySpecException, NotSupportedException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    PrivateKey key = null; 

    InputStream inpusStream = new FileInputStream(getFile2(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_NAME));
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(inpusStream, Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_PASSWORD);
    } finally {
        if (inpusStream != null)
            inpusStream.close();
    }
    Enumeration<String> s = keyStore.aliases();

    while (s.hasMoreElements())
        System.err.println("[ " + s.nextElement() + " ]");

    //Generate password for this private key
    char [] pass = getKeyPassword(c, alias, id);


    if (read == true) { //If reading/getting private key from file store
        boolean isKeyEntry = keyStore.isKeyEntry(alias);//Check if there is a key with the alias deviceSerialnumber
        if (!isKeyEntry) {//No key with this alias exists
            throw new KeyStoreException("No key with alias " + alias + " exists!");
        }

        key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, pass);

    } else { //Writing/ saving key to the file store
        keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, c , pass, new Certificate[] { createCertificate() });
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_NAME), true);
        try { 
            keyStore.store(out, pass);

            System.out.println("Alias exists = " + keyStore.containsAlias(alias));
        } finally { 
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
        } 
    }

    s = keyStore.aliases();

    while (s.hasMoreElements())
        System.err.println("( " + s.nextElement() + " )");

    return key;
}
```

Output:

```
[ mykey ]
( 123 )
( mykey )
Alias exists = true
[ mykey ]
Exception in thread "main" java.security.KeyStoreException: No key with alias 123 exists!
```

Why is the key not being saved to the JKS file file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in the `FileOutputStream` was pointing to the wrong file.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_NAME), true);
```

Should be using the `getFile2` method like this:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getFile2(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_NAME));
```

As Palamino pointed out, don't need to include `true` in the `FileOutputStream` constructor.

Also the key store should have been using the JKS file password, not the password that is generated by `getKeyPassword()`.

Changed this:

```
keyStore.store(out, pass);
```

To use the JKS file password, like this:

```
keyStore.store(out, Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: what getFile2 method? there is no such method in your question. This question doesn't seem to fit in stackoverflow as it really doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: It is in `getOrSetPrivateKey` method in `FileInputStream` constructor

Comment: but where it is defined?

Comment: Methods are not in constructors. Answer is incomplete.

Comment: What are you talking about? the getFile2 method is just to return a File, there is no need to show how to do that, it is not relevant to the question. Answer is complete, all the changes noted are what solved the question. So take away the down vote.

Answer (score 3):

You are appending to the existing keystore instead of replacing it because you are passing "true" to the FileOutputStream constructor.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_NAME), true);
```

Replace the line above with the following:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Constants.JKS_PRIVATE_FILE_NAME));
```

Comment: The key is still not being saved in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Keystore on VM, then you can Run the Keystore as Administrator. Redo all the steps as per your requirement.
And then again try saving the file.

In my case, the issue was that I was not running the Keystore as Administrator.